# Serialization problem in apache beam, and Big Query TableSchema

Tags: csv, serialization, google-bigquery, pipeline, apache-beam

and thank you for your support.

I am currently experimenting with Apache Beam to learn as much as possible about how it works. I am facing an issue with the serialization of the com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema. I have read that it is not possible to serialize TableSchema, and I am exploring potential workarounds for this challenge. So far i do have my superclass:

```
public class TransformBasic extends DoFn<String, TableRow>  {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransformBasic.class);
protected final TupleTag<TableRow> outputTag;
protected final TupleTag<TableRow> failureTag;

private transient com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema tableSchema;
private String whoAmI;
private String header;




public TransformBasic(String whoAmI, String header, TupleTag<TableRow> outputTag, TupleTag<TableRow> failureTag) {

    this.whoAmI = whoAmI;
    this.header = header;
    this.outputTag = outputTag;
    this.failureTag = failureTag;
}

public TransformBasic() {
    this.outputTag = null;
    this.failureTag = null;
}


@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
     tableSchema = getTableSchemaByName();

    //Csv line
    String line = c.element();

    //BigQuery row
    TableRow row = new TableRow();

    //Csv parser
    CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder()
            .withSeparator(',')
            .build();

    try {
        //If csv line is different from header
        if (!line.equalsIgnoreCase(header)) {
            String[] csvColumns = csvParser.parseLine(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < csvColumns.length; i++) {
                TableFieldSchema bigqueryColumn = tableSchema.getFields().get(i);
                String newBigqueryColumns = replaceCharacters(bigqueryColumn.getName());
                row.set(newBigqueryColumns, csvColumns[i]);
            }
            c.output(outputTag,row);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("FAILURE in " + whoAmI.toUpperCase() + e);

        Failure failure = new Failure(
                LocalDate.now().toString(),
                whoAmI,
                line,
                e.toString());

        c.output(failureTag, failure.getAsTableRow());
    }


}

     
//****************************
// HERE IS THE SERIALIZATION WORKAROUND SOLUTION ( NOT WORKING ) ----------------------------
//****************************
protected TableSchema getTableSchemaByName() {

    // Use the whoAmI variable to determine the schema
    if ("L".equals(whoAmI)) {
        return getTableSchemaL();
    } else if ("P".equals(whoAmI)) {
        return getTableSchemaP();
    } else {
        // Handle other cases or throw an exception
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown class: " + whoAmI);
    }
}}
```

then i create the son class:

```
public class TransformL extends TransformBasic  {


public static final  TupleTag<TableRow> OUTPUT_TAGS_L=new TupleTag<TableRow>() {};
public static final  TupleTag<TableRow> FAILURE_TAGS_L = new TupleTag<TableRow>() {};
private static final String WHO_AM_I = "l";
private static final String HEADER_L = "metric,scen,sec,year,value,id";

public TransformL() {
    super(WHO_AM_I, HEADER_L,OUTPUT_TAGS_L,FAILURE_TAGS_L);

}}
```

the table schema i am using is:

```
    public class TableSchema {
   public static com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema getTableSchemaL() {
        List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("metric"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("scen"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("sec"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("year"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("value"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("id"));

        return new com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema().setFields(fields);
    }
}
```

and i am testing this implementation like this:

```
public class TransformLitUwTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransformLitUwTest.class);


    @Rule
    public final transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();
      public void testTransformL() {
    
    
            // Create a sample input data
            String fakeInput = "metric,scen,sec,year,value,id\n" +
                    "metric1,scen1,10,2022,100,id1\n" +
                    "metric2,scen2,20,2022,200,id2";
            PCollection<String> inputCollection = pipeline
                    .apply("CreateFakeInput", org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create.of(fakeInput));
    
    
            // Apply your TransformLitUw transformation
            PCollectionTuple outputTuple = inputCollection.apply("TransformL", ParDo.of(new 
            TransformL())
                    .withOutputTags(TransformLitUw.OUTPUT_TAGS_L, 
            TupleTagList.of(TransformLitUw.FAILURE_TAGS_L)));
    
            // Get the PCollection with successful outputs
            PCollection<TableRow> outputCollection = 
            outputTuple.get(TransformLitUw.OUTPUT_TAGS_L);
            
            // Log output of PCollection
            outputCollection.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Void>() {
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(@Element TableRow c) {
                // Print each TableRow to the console
                LOG.info("TABLE ROW -------------------------------------> " + c.toString());
              }
            }));
    
            //Logic for asset equal (implementation omitted)
    
            // Run the pipeline
            pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
        }
}
```

I removed some code for clarity, but if necessary, i will include the complete code.

The initial workaround involved creating a class in the parent that would call the TableSchema and use it in the parent method. However, this approach is still not working, and the debugging process is not providing enough clarity on where changes should be made.
i would like to keep the idea of having a super class, this is kind of unnecessary for the table schema that i have, but i would like to experiment also with the inheritance method.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research on serialization and fixed the errors that were appearing in the console. Basically, I also needed to include the implementation of serialization in the test class. This is because, with the way I implemented the classes and the various pipelines ( the particular error for the serializzation is due of the Logg of the ArrayTable "LOG.info("TABLE ROW ParDO-------------------------------------> " + c.toString());", if u remove it is unnecessary to put the "implement Serialization" on test class ), I had to pass the tableSchema at the test class level as well. So, I changed the class as follows

```
public class TransformLitUwTest implements Serializable {
             // the rest of the implementation goes here
}
```

During the implementation, I also discovered another error at this point::

```
    // Apply TransformLitUw transformation
    PCollectionTuple outputTuple = inputCollection.apply("TransformLitUw", ParDo.of(new TransformLitUw())
            .withOutputTags(TransformLitUw.OUTPUT_TAGS_LIT_UW, TupleTagList.of(TransformLitUw.FAILURE_TAGS_LIT_UW)));
```

In this case, because the DoFn of TransformLitUw() receives a String and returns TableSchema, I had to read the 'fake CSV' as an array of strings in the following way:

```
        PCollection<String> inputCollection = pipeline
            .apply("CreateFakeInput", org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create.of(Arrays.asList(fakeInput.split("\n"))));
```

I hope that this information will help someone facing the serialization problem and guide them on how to resolve it